# Equations in ORDER BY statements

Tags: sql

Say I want to include a  `where` clause based on two columns, X and Z. I'd then order by `(3 * X) + Z DESC`.  Is that possible?  I could not find anything about arithmetic in the order by column.

So the statement would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM mySweetTable 
WHERE U LIKE "as%" or V LIKE "as%" 
ORDER BY (3 * X + Z) DESC
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (3 * X + Z) as OrderCondition
FROM mySweetTable 
WHERE U LIKE "as%" or V LIKE "as%" 
ORDER BY OrderCondition DESC
```

Comment: Thank you, That worked out perfectly.!  Sorry it took me a bit to respond.

Comment: The `OrderCondition` column would be returned as part of the SELECT statement right? How would you get rid of that column?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that X and Z are numeric columns then there's no problem with this.